# Batch script doesn't work when I open a file with it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I decided to make a batch file that encrypts files using OpenSSL's AES-256-CBC.

I made it so that the first argument is the file path to be encrypted.

The batch file then copies the file and encrypts it adding the extension `.encw to its name.

Here is the script:

```
echo off
set file=%1
echo s
echo %file%
echo e
if [%1]==[] (
    echo Missing file parameter.
    exit /B
)
if exist %file% (
    echo %file%
    for %%a in (%file%) do set "p_dir=%%~dpa"
    for %%F in (%file%) do set "fname=%%~nxF"
    echo %p_dir%
    echo %fname%
    set encfile="%p_dir%%fname%.enc"
    echo openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in %file% -out %encfile%
    echo %encfile%
) else (
echo File does not exist.
)
pause
```

This works when you open a command prompt and enter the path of the batch file and the path of the file to be encrypted.

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG3gS.png)

But when someone were to open that file with it *(dragging a file onto the batch in File Explorer)* the new `.enc` copy is not created because of some reason the parent file and the file name are blank
.

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Dht.png)

Why is this happening?

I made it so it would print the OpenSSL command instead of executing it to avoid issues.

Comment: What does `echo %file%` display ?

Comment: I accidentally posted this too early its edited now

Comment: that was the problem, thanks

Comment: Nest time please provide the output as text, not as a screenshot. And if you wipe out your name don't forget the title of the command line window ;-)